# Drupal Admin 7 | How to sort particular dropdown values coming from taxonomy in one of the form?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am new to drupal and working on an existing system. In the admin part of drupal, the form contains various elements and I want to sort of the drop down elements in ascending order. The values comes from the taxonomy manager. But I don't know how to modify the same. The taxonomy_get_children already has the sorting function. It sorts by weight first and then by name. But its not working.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance
Srividhya

Comment: So, would you solve with a working 'taxonomy_get_children' ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess your taxonomy output has been overriden somewhere with a custom sort, try to disable any module that might be taxonomy related modules to see which one might be at fault.

Otherwise if you can't disable or modify that module why don't you sort youself the output of taxonomy_get_children right before you put them in the drop down element ?